# ¿Obtener unos campos para crear una subconsulta trayendo, detalles de un objeto y los indices que tiene en SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql

estoy realizando una consulta EN SQL SERVER.
Necesito conocer el objeto, tipo objeto, Tamaño del objeto, Indices que tenga dicho objeto y el porcentaje de fragmentación de cada indice.

Mi duda radica en las tablas para poder traer la fragmentación de cada indice y el tamaño del objeto.

Esto es lo que llevo:

```
 select  distinct so.name,so.type,(so.type_desc),ps.row_count as 
         IdnIsThisIsSize,idx.index_id  from  sys.objects so 
         inner join sys.dm_db_partition_stats ps
         on so.object_id = ps.object_id inner join sys.indexes idx on 
         idx.index_id = ps.index_id;
```